# Matrix multiplication result in NaN by using Mac osx Accelerate framework

Tags: macos, numpy, nan, caffe, blas

When I use `numpy.dot` for `ndarray`, a strange phenomenon happened. Here is the info of the `numpy` installed on my MacOSX:

```
{'define_macros': [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)],
 'extra_compile_args': ['-msse3',
 '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers'],
 'extra_link_args': ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']}
```

Assume there are two matrices `W(m, k)`, `X(k, n)`, and `y = W.dot(X)`, I found there are some positions in `y` is `NaN`. For example: `y[i][j] == Nan`. And then I do the following operation:

```
a = W[i].dot(X[:,j])
```

And I found `a` is not a `Nan`! Besides, I also found that the positions of `Nan` in y are difference between each experiment.

I used the same `W` and `X` and do that operation in another PC with `Ubuntu14.04`, the info of the `numpy` in that PC is:

```
{'define_macros': [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.10.1\\""')],
 'include_dirs': ['/usr/include/atlas'],
 'language': 'c',
 'libraries': ['f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas'],
 'library_dirs': ['/usr/lib/atlas-base']}
```

`y = W.dot(X)` is normal and there are no any `NaN` in it.

I know how `numpy.dot` is implemented and `cblas_dgemm()` is called for the double-precision matrix-times-matrix case. **So Is there any bug in the MacOSX Accelerate framework??**

---

The matrix `W` is the weight blobs in the `caffe.convolutionLayer`, and `X` is the input to this layer. I also used `caffe` on my MacOSX, which used the `Accelerate.framework` as its matrix multiplication library.That strange things also happened.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, verify if there is any division by zero?

Comment: @HarshWardhan The experiment I took contains only matrix multiplication, no division at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrices contain zero and inf/-inf then the product zero*inf seems to be defined as nan. There seem to be inconsistencies in the BLAS libraries, mine (libblas3) sometimes omits the NaN values and gives different results for differently sized matrices. Compare the positions which differ by AxB == trans(trans(A)*trans(B)) where A and B are matrices and trans() is the transpose of a matrix.